# Valgrind complains about using conditional jumps that depend on uninitialized bytes

Tags: c++, valgrind

I had this problem appear in a module of a larger program I am working on and here is a small simulation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int key;
    vector<int> connections;
};

int main(void){

    int size = 10;
    node *A;

    A=(node*)malloc((size)*sizeof(node));

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        A[i].key = i;
        if(i%2 == 0) A[i].connections.push_back(i);
    }

    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if(A[i].connections.size() > 0) {
            cout << A[i].key << "---" << A[i].connections.size() << endl;
        }
    }

    free(A);

    return 0;
}
```

This is a small part of what I get when running `valgrind ./testCode`

```
==30433== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==30433==    at 0x400F63: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (stl_vector.h:915)
==30433==    by 0x400DF0: main (testCode.cpp:25)
```

from my understanding the problem is that there is an if statement inside the `push_back` function of the vector that uses some value that is uninitialized. I am not sure what exactly. After playing around, it turns out the problem is that I use `malloc`. If I use `calloc` I won't get any warnings at all. The same if I use `new`. However in all cases the program behaves exactly the same way. What is happening here? Is it safe to use `malloc` even though I get all these warnings?

Comment: So, the question is, why is valgrind confused about the effect of code whose behavior is undefined? `A[i].connections` has not been constructed, so there is nothing sensible that you can do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not safe to use `malloc` here.

`malloc` is the C way of allocating memory. It doesn't take C++ constructors into account.

`calloc` is also C, but it zero-initializes your memory. That's why `std::vector` works (it is, however, also undefined behavior, because there may be a `vector` implementation which needs to be initialized to something else than zero).

There are many ways to get around that problem:

- Use `new Node` instead.
- If you cannot do that, you can at least do a placement new on the memory that `malloc` returns (`new (ptr) Node()`).
- Use smart pointers and `make_shared` or `make_unique`. That way, you don't even need to take care of freeing your memory.
- The best way is probably to use `std::vector` (as suggested in another answer) or `std::array`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using vector<>, you should always avoid malloc and free as they don't initialize constructors and instead use new and delete and smart pointers.

However, there is rarely a need to use new/delete since vector accomplishes the same thing with a similar memory and access footprint.

This implementation wraps `node` in a vector and eliminates direct memory allocation as it is done automatically by vector<> while maintaining the same, traditional usage style.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    int key;
    vector<int> connections;
};

int main(void) {
    // original with similar memory footprint and access characteristics using modern C++ vector<>
    int size = 10;
    vector<node> A(size);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        A[i].key = i;
        if (i % 2 == 0) A[i].connections.push_back(i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        if (A[i].connections.size() > 0) {
            cout << A[i].key << "---" << A[i].connections.size() << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

connections inside node is not set. This is because you use malloc to create yr Node instance. That just gives you raw uninitialized memory. You MUST use new to allocate objects in c++ programs not malloc. New allocates the memory then runs the constructor

ie

```
node *A = new Node();
```

and delete to release it - not free

In fact you need an array of Node objects. So do what ben says. Make a vector of them

But anyway, never ever use malloc / free in a c++ program unless you are really sure you know what you are doing

Comment: `A=(node*)malloc((size)*sizeof(node));` the op allocates space for 10 nodes, not 1, this is not equivalent code. (`for(i=0;i<size;i++) {` Then they use all 10 as well ...)

Comment: :-) - we are right as to why valgrind complains, I did not read the fact that he attempted to allocate an array of node objects.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that it is because `malloc` does not call the constructor of `node`. Since this is c++, `node` is not a struct as it was in c, it is a class. It has an implicit constructor, which needs to be called at instantiation. This means the vector is also not created properly.

You should do 2 things:

1. Avoid calling new, there is no need in this case, just use `node A[10]` or better yet `std::vector<node> A`.
2. If you cant do that always use `new` in c++, so that the objects are created correctly.

If you absolutely must use `malloc`, then you will need to call the `placement new` to construct your struct anyway (`new (&A[0]) node()`), so really just dont use `malloc`.

Comment: he doesnt want a vector of nodes - he wants a node object that has inside it a vector of ints

Comment: @pm100, No, he wants 10 `nodes`. Therefore a `vector` of nodes is perfect here.